# how to retrieve the list of public key addresses of all validators?

Tags: validator, account, address, public

I am writing a custom `gRPC` server(not in runtime) and i want to retrieve the public keys of the validators to verify messages signed by them, but i need their public key addresses, how to do that in substrate?

Comment: What public key do you want? GRANDPA? BABE? Stash?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier aura !

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the session pallet in your runtime.

```
PolkadotApps -> chain state -> session -> queuedKeys
```

[image]

If you want to do this in code.

Query the `twox128(b"Session") + twox128(b"QueuedKeys")`.

Comment: i want to do it in rust though?

Comment: You could use [Subalfred](https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred/blob/2e769b1da67ba2cc9ade04ff9dc0543f889d6d62/substrate-minimal/substorager/src/lib.rs#L90) to calculate the storage key. Then query the storage key through rpc use reqwest or whatever you like.

Or you could use subxt. Please check its [document](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/concurrent_storage_requests.rs) for more detail.

Comment: what do you mean by Sublfred and storage key, ps: i can use subxt

Comment: 1. Use it to calculate the storage key
2. Pass the storage key to rpc endpint `state_getStorage`
3. Get the result

Comment: https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/state-transitions-and-storage/